# unix time in PHP table row to normal time

Tags: php, html, unix-timestamp

I have a php look up from a drop down list. This will look up changes to a specific staff's time card and return to a table. Works really well but I am having trouble returning the results from Line 2 and 5 and 7 to show real time not unix time, 2 is date effected, 5 is date requested and 7 in date approved/changed. 
This is the code i am using.

```
<table border="1" width="75%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td align="center">Date Effected</td>
<td align="center">Status requested</td>
<td align="center">Requested by</td>
<td align="center">Date requested</td>
<td align="center">Amended by</td>
<td align="center">Date amended</td>
</tr>
<?php
$host = "host";
$user = "USER";
$pass = "PWORD";
$dbname = "DB";
$loc = $fgmembersite->UserLocation();
$term = $_GET['button'];
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().":    ".mysql_error()."<BR>");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$query= "select * from $loc where User_id=$term";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
while ($line = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td align="center">'.$line[2].'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.$line[3].'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.$line[4].'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.$line[5].'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.$line[6].'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.$line[7].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

any help gratefully revived. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, stop using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) as your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

If I understand correctly, you're storing the date as a unix timestamp and need to convert it. It can be done with MySQL or PHP.

With MySQL, you can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()`.

> ```
> mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219);
>     -> '2007-11-30 10:30:19'
> ```

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

With PHP, you can use `date`.

> ```
> echo date("F j", 1196440219);
>    //November 30
> ```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

I would also recommend that you specify a column list in your query, and use those columns rather than the index value.

Comment: Thanks was unaware functions are deprecated, trouble using a brain that was educated many years ago and not used. Will be changing to $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database"); i will try your answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did I misunderstand or are you looking for the Date function? If so, try this:

```
while ($line = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td align="center">'.date("d-m-Y", $line[2]).'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.$line[3].'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.$line[4].'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.date("d-m-Y", $line[5]).'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.$line[6].'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.date("d-m-Y",$line[7]).'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
```

The function is documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the PHP level, or on the MySQL level

In PHP you can use date create from format, the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class in PHP is very handy/flexible

```
// add this function to your script
function convertUnixTime($timeStamp) {
    $date = date_create_from_format('U', $timeStamp);

    // check the php docs for different ways you can format dates
    return date_format($date, 'm-d-Y');
}

// then update your echo statements 
echo '<td align="center">'.convertUnixTime($line[7]).'</td>';
```

See the [DateTime->format docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for more info